# How to build ruby code in Sublime text 2?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I have ubuntu. I saved my file as untitled.rb `print "hello"`
If I build this, I see nothing in build results.
Build system is Ruby.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, please improve your question and ***provide your code***.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [ask] for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "puts "hello"" is all my code, aslo build system is Ruby.

Comment: Ruby code doesn't need building to be run. Just open a terminal window and type `ruby /path/to/untitled.rb`

Comment: It mean that i can't  see result in sublime-text 2 ?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't try that. But basically ruby isn't a compiled language and hence I don't think a ruby *script* can be *built*, it just has to be run.

Comment: Running "ruby untitled.rb" is what sublime's build command does. You should be seeing the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work because system's language was Russian.

Answer (score 2):

I believe he means running ruby code in the Sublime Text console. To do this, all you have to do is have your file (with the code) saved then press CMD + SHIFT + B and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sublime_plugin.py", line 337, in run_
  File "./exec.py", line 130, in run
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 25-33: ordinal not in range(128) (it's my result)

Comment: wait, do you have ruby installed at all?

Comment: I did it with "sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1"

Comment: maybe you should check if the install succeeded. try running some ruby code in the console to see if it works.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: ok, try running this with the console as above (CMD + SHFT + B) `puts "hey".encode('utf-8')` what do you get? if it works then you might consider changing your terminal's encoding.